# How to know port number of oracle 11g xe

Tags: oracle, jdbc, oracle11g, port-number

How to find the **port number**, **hostname** of

> oracle 11g XE

?

Comment: Do you have access to the database server, can you log on to the machine?

Comment: it is in sqlnet.ora file

Answer (score 3):

By using the following function:

```
SQL> select DBMS_XDB.GETHTTPPORT from dual;

GETHTTPPORT
-----------
       8080

SQL>
```

P.S. Bah, not *that* port, I'm afraid. TNSPING might be what you're looking for:

```
C:\>tnsping xe

TNS Ping Utility for 64-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production on 28-SVI-2
018 21:03:53

Copyright (c) 1997, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Used parameter files:
C:\E_0_library\sqlnet.ora


Used TNSNAMES adapter to resolve the alias
Attempting to contact (DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = my-pc)(PORT = 1521)) (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = DEDICATED) (SERVICE_NAME = XE)))
                                                                               ^^^^^^^^^^^
                                                                                  this

OK (20 msec)

C:\>
```

Comment: Sure; while installing Oracle Application Express. Though, that's the HTTP port, but I think that you need the database port, such as 1521 which is the default. I don't know the way to find that one in a simple manner, unless `tnsping xe`'s result satisfies you.